# How to stop a SpriteKit node completly with code (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

In SpriteKit is there a way to stop the motion of an object completely. I know that you can start moving with this code:

```
line.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -30))
```

But I want to know how to stop the object that I call line in the example.

Answer (score 1):

set velocity to 0.0

```
line.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
```